# Functions differentiable at zero

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a case where a function $f$ that is not differentiable at $0$ and a function $g$ that is differentiable at $0$ where $f+g$ is differentiable at $0$?

Comment: Do you know about [accepting answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)? So far you haven't accepted any answers to your questions.

Comment: No i don't. Is it the check mark below the vote options?

Comment: Yes it is. You seem to have found it (you accepted Sheol's answer below). You may want to consider going over your other questions and seeing if there are any answers there that are worth accepting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One has: $$f=f+g-g.$$
Then, if $f+g$ and $g$ are differentiable at the origin, $f$ is differentiable at the origin with: $$f'(0)=(f+g)'(0)-g'(0).$$
Therefore, the answer to your question is no.

Comment: dear prof. @C.Falcon can you help me for ask Math question in stack.exchange??..Because this is so hard question for ask for me..And I can not turn the question into mathematics language..(+latex and english language)..Please..can you help me as your Little student.. :( I prepared direk link.. Can you look??Do you have some time?..

Answer (score 12):

Hint:

let $f+g=h$, if $h$ is differentiable and $g$ is differentiable what can we say about $f=h-g$ ?